# Spark Ar Code Autocomplete don't works in Visual Studio Code

Tags: types, visual-studio-code, intellisense, spark-ar-studio

I followed de official documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ar-studio/scripting/basics/#code-autocomplete .

When I edit the script.js in *VScode* into *Mac* or *Windows*,  the autocomplite like discribed on docs dont't works.

- Search a VScode extension for Spark Ar scrips support, but, doesn't exists.
- Search @types/sparkar, but, doesn't exists.
- I'm doing a type, based on docs in [Scripting Object Reference](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/reference/scripting/summary)

Answer (score 2):

Autocomplete works! I'am using macOS, but steps should be the same on Windows. Here is what I've done to get it:

1) Install Visual Studio IntelliCode extension

[image]

2)Quit both SparkAr and VSCode.

[image]

3)Open SparkAr and from there open your script.

And you will get it!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but if someone gets here when searching for the same problem in a more recent version (v101 in my case) here is one solution I found. In this version, the content in the folder '/private/var/folders/.../skylight-typedefs' is not included for some reason (the path can be found in the tsconfig.json that is created when adding a script to a project), so the IDE can't find the type definitions. I installed an older version and manually copied the files and added them back after upgrading to 101, then it worked.

Answer (score -2):

I was in the exact situation.

On windows, you may also try to open Spark AR in Administrator mode before opening VScode

This solved the issue for me