# Old JS script in SparkAR stoped working with multiple errors

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I created this JS script a long time ago for a face filter effect. After the new SparkAR update I needed to refresh the project to make it available for the users, but my old script now shows me a lot of errors.

The script is used to change textures assigned to some materials when I click on different 3D planes in the scene.

I tried to create a new script to see if the syntax has changed, but the brand new script also has errors. I looked in the documentation, the syntax seems to be right. How can I fix them?

Example from my script:

[image]

[image]

Comment: For autocomplete :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339490/spark-ar-code-autocomplete-dont-works-in-visual-studio-code/59393004#59393004
The api changed a lot, check the official docs for refrence.

Comment: Thank you @lisichkaggg, if you'll add it as as answer I'll be able to accept it